# If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of size $\ell$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ what is the probability that they have at least $m$ elements in common?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are answers for checking if the two sets are disjoint. But I could not find anything about them having a certain number of common elements.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are two subsets such that $A \cap B = C$ where $C$ has $m$ elements, then $A = C \cup D_1$ and $B = C \cup D_2$ where $D_1 \cap D_2 = \phi$. If you find in how many ways $C$ can be chosen, you can reduce the problem to the disjoint subset case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which elements $S_1$ contains doesn’t matter for this, just which elements $S_2$ contains. I am going to assume that $\ell$ can range from $1$ through $n$ and that a set can contain an element only once.

I am going to draw up an analogous problem that will make this one easier to think through:

> There are $n$ cards laying in front of you, facedown, where $\ell$ of them are red and $n-\ell$ of them are black. What is the probability that at least $m$ of the cards you draw are red given that you draw $\ell$ cards without replacement.

Here, our red cards are the elements of $S_1$ and the cards you draw are the elements of $S_2$.

This is a hypergeometric probability distribution, because

- each card drawn is either red or it isn’t
- the probability of selecting a red card changes each time

Let $X$ be the random variable that represents the number of red cards drawn. The formula is that

$$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

- $N$ is the population size
- $K$ is the number of success states in the population
- $n$ is the number of draws
- $k$ is the number of successes you end up seeing

For us, our population is the $n$ cards laying facedown in front of us; the success states are the red cards, of which there are $\ell$; we are drawing $\ell$ cards; and we want to see $k$ range anywhere from $m$ all the way up to the maximum, $\ell$. Thus, we want to calculate

$$\begin{align}
P(m\le X\le \ell) = P(X=m) + P(X=m+1) + \cdots + P(X=\ell) = \sum_{k=\ell}^m \frac{\binom \ell k \binom{n-\ell}{\ell-k}}{\binom n \ell} \\
\end{align}$$

Since you haven’t specified, I am going to assume sigma notation is fine for you.

Comment: A non-sigma solution would be nice. Does there exist a closed form summation for this series?

Comment: @1026501 That is the closed form since taking $m\to\infty$ would get kinda meaningless